# Losing Kafka data on reset

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying out Kafka, and I'm having a problem with losing data during reboots.

**Setup:** I have one VM with Zookeeper installed, and two other VMs with Kafka installed. I'm testing with a topic that has `replication-factor=2`.

The test case is this:

1. send message 'Hello'
2. Reboot
3. send message 'Hello again'.
4. Make sure that Hello is offset 0 and Hello again is offset 1.

This works when:

- Kafka1 & Kafka2 both stay up (no reboots).
- Kafka1 stays up. Kafka2 is down for some portion.
- Kafka2 stays up. Kafka1 is down for some portion.

However, if I reboot both Kafka servers, then the 'Hello' message is lost, and 'Hello again' becomes offset 0. I would expect it to persist through the reboot.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are your logs being stored in /tmp?

Comment: They were. Changing that setting fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Oh yes looks like the reboot vs reset in the titled caused it to be missed in Google.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look on `min.insync.replicas` in your broker configuration.

This setting is crucial for the durable writing to Kafka. It basically says how much replicas have to ack the write for considering this write as successful. The default value for ISR is 1. So only one replica have to remain in sync in order to consider the write as successful.

On the flip side, your producer config is important as well. If you write messages with `acks=1` only the current leader will acknowledge the write. So try to use something like `acks=all` or in your case `acks=2`.

Comment: This didn't directly address the problem but helped nonetheless. Thank you.